# Customs NSView size reverts to original size, when initiating a print operation

Tags: swift, printing, size, nsview, nsscrollview

I have a custom NSView in which i draw some rectangles. I also change
programmatically the size of the view using handles which the user can drag with the mouse. The custom view resides in a NSScrollView and the Document.xib uses Auto Layout.

Everything works OK, and the custom NSView changes its size perfectly.
However, when i try to print or create a pdf file with the contents of the view, the custom NSView reverts its size back to the original size when the Document.xib was loaded.

Has anyone of you faced the same problem?

I am using Swift and XCode 6.4